# Azure Pipeline increment xcode build number

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on an Azure DevOps pipeline for an Xcode 14 iOS project, and I can't figure out, how to automate incrementing the build number and committing it to the repository. I have found a DevOps task called `Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android` that offers build number bumping, but it doesn't quite suit my scenario. My build number is not stored directly in the info.plist file, but it's located under the `Identity` section in the project file, referenced as `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` in `Custom iOS Target Properties`.

How can I increment the build number every time the pipeline runs and save it?